# mariadb replication over ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication, mariadb

I'm trying to do mariadb replication over a ssh tunnel. Here is my config.
First, I created a ssh tunnel from my replication server(R1) to my Master server (M1).

```
ssh -L 13306:localhost:3306 -p 22111 admin@M1 -f -N
```

Both the mariadb instances are already running on both the servers. And I have already created a replication user on the M1 mariadb instance.

```
CREATE USER 'replication'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'xxxx';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE on *.* to 'replication'@'127.0.0.1' REQUIRE SSL;
```

From R1 I check if I can connect to the M1 mariadb instance.

```
mysql -u replication -pxxxx -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP -P 13306
```

The above operation succeeded.
But now, when I instruct the replication instance R1 to **change master** and **start slave**, it fails.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1', MASTER_USER='replication', MASTER_PASSWORD='xxxx', MASTER_PORT=13306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000022', MASTER_LOG_POS=9164599, MASTER_SSL=1, MASTER_SSL_CA='/etc/tls/ca-cert.pem', MASTER_SSL_CERT='/etc/tls/client-cert.pem', MASTER_SSL_KEY='/etc/tls/client-key.pem',  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10;
START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 13306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000022
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 9164599
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000022
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 9164599
              Relay_Log_Space: 249
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/tls/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/tls/client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key: /etc/tls/client-key.pem
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'ubi_replication@127.0.0.1:13306' - retry-time: 10  retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
               Master_SSL_Crl: /etc/tls/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos:
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help pointing to the error config is highly welcome.

Regards,

Ashutosh Singh

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem using a non standard port for SELinux.

Need to make sure you have the tools to check SELinux manage tool:

```
yum install -y setroubleshoot-server selinux-policy-devel
```

You can check allowable ports for mysql service by running:

```
semanage port -l | grep mysqld_port_t
```

Then you can add the port to the mysql service by running:

```
semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 13306
```

Then restart your slave and it should connect.